# adding full stops to the ends of a paragraphs

Tags: php

I'm taking the text from a place where it was created with *WYSIWYG* editor so it's full of html markup. (`b`, `p`, `strong`, etc.)

What I need to do is, before stripping the markup is make sure every line/parapgraph ends with a full stop. If there is a full stop don't do anything but if the character before the </p> is not a full stop, add one.

I've tried:

```
$str = ereg_replace("[A-Za-z0-9]&lt;/p>", ".&lt;/p>", $str );
```

But that gets rid of the last letter in the sentence as well (which I understand it should). So `the end&lt;/p>` becomes `the en.&lt;/p>`. Is there any nifty way to do what I want to achieve?

Comment: `ereg` has been deprecated for literally years. You should NOT be using it in new code. Pretend it never existed, and switch to `preg` instead. As well, don't use regexes to mangle html. you'll just tear out any hair you've got left. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: So true ... so little hair left to tear!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, using 2 regex backreferences $1 and $2.

The 1st regex defining **$1** in the parentheses says: not a period, not a space [SP, Tab, ...] that followed by any number of spaces or none. In a simple word, the whole regex states: the last **SOLID - VISIBLE** character preceding "<" is not a period ".".

**$2** is an HTML tag such as b, p, li, strong, h1,...

#### test without point:

```
$str = "<p>This is a good text, but it's
very tedious  </p>";
preg_replace("/([^\.\s])[\s]*<\/([[:alnum:]]+)>/", "$1.</$2>", $str);
echo $str;
```

Gives:
    This is a good text, but it's very tedious.

#### test with point:

```
$str = "<p>This is a good text, but it's
very tedious.   </p>";
preg_replace("/([^\.\s])[\s]*<\/([[:alnum:]]+)>/", "$1.</$2>", $str);
echo $str;
```

Gives:
    This is a good text, but it's very tedious.

#### The simplified regex:

```
$str = preg_replace("/([a-z0-9])<\/p>/i", "$1.</p>", $str);
```

adds a full stop to any paragraph that ends with a number or ASCII letter and doesn't have a full stop. The HTML tag, such as P or p, is here case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks - that works a dream. Although I think your first version should be on the page here in case someone needs it. $str = preg_replace("/([A-Za-z0-9])<\/p>/", "$1. </p>", $str); add a full stop to any paragraph that ends with a number or letter and doesn't have a full stop.

Comment: Yes this has been repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative lookbehind works:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(?<!\.)&lt;\/p>/", "$1.&lt;\/p>", $str);
```